# Передача данных List на jsp страницу

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Проблема в том что данные по какой-то причине не отображаются и таблица с помощью цикла не заполняется. Я предполагаю что данные почему-то не доходят до jsp, но совсем не вижу причину этого.

vote.jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${restaurants}" var="restaurant" >
        <jsp:useBean id="restaurant" type="model.Restaurant"/>
        <tr>
            <td>${restaurant.id}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.name}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.snack}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.starter}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.main}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.drink}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.dessert}</td>
            <td>${restaurant.dateTime}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

VoteServlet:

```
public static final List<Restaurant> RESTAURANTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Restaurant(1, "name1", "snack1", "starter1", "main1", "drink1", "dessert1",
                LocalDateTime.of(2011, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0)),
        new Restaurant(2, "name2", "snack2", "starter2", "main2", "drink2", "dessert2",
                LocalDateTime.of(2012, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0)),
        new Restaurant(3, "name3", "snack3", "starter3", "main3", "drink3", "dessert3",
                LocalDateTime.of(2013, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0)),
        new Restaurant(4, "name4", "snack4", "starter4", "main4", "drink4", "dessert4",
                LocalDateTime.of(2014, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0)),
        new Restaurant(5, "name5", "snack5", "starter5", "main5", "drink5", "dessert5",
                LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0))
);

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("getAll");
    req.setAttribute("restaurants", RESTAURANTS);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/vote.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: Первое, попробуй выводить без `dateTime` , скорее всего jstl не понимает как ее выводить, удали `<td>${restaurant.dateTime}</td>`. Второе, замени `items="${restaurants}"` на `items="${requestScope.restaurants}"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы достать обьект из request scope:

```
<jsp:useBean scope="request" ... />
```

Так как **по умолчанию** scope = page.

**P. S.** В данном случае можете вообще убрать тег jsp:useBean.

Comment: тоже самое, таблица все равно не заполняется данными

Comment: @RomanAbaev сервлет вызывается? Есть "getAll" в логах?

Comment: спасибо, настроил логирование и стало работать, но небольшая загвоздка, у меня есть есть начальная страница index.html, на которой есть ссылка на vote.jsp и при первом переходе ничего не происходит, а если с vote.jsp вернуться на index.html и опять перейти на vote.jsp, все отображается, получается что при первом переходе почему-то не обрабатывается корректно (и "getAll" в логах тоже не появляется только со второго раза)

Comment: @RomanAbaev если предоставите больше кода, возможно смогу помочь. А так очень тяжело сказать в чем проблема.

Comment: буду признателен: https://github.com/RomanAbaev/votesystem